# No components being touched when keyboard is opened

Tags: android, button, android-keypad

I have ImageButton and an EditText, when the keyboard is opened that is the edit text is focused the imagebutton on click listener does not work

I already tried removing the requestfocus in oncreate in method

Comment: Can you share your code? Because in my opinion this should work.

Comment: Hi, @Allinone51, I can't sahre the code but can you tell me is the issue of focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the issue was because of an extra view